# Remove 'some' specific text from an input?

Tags: jquery, input, indexof

I have few buttons of which each button is assigned a class with a number. When I click each button, the number is submitted in an input. If I double click that button, I want that number/value to get deleted from the input **but only that number**.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/HC5W7/

and this is my code:

```
$("div").live('click',function() {
  var a = $('input').val();
  var b = $(this).attr('class')
  var c;
  if ( $("input").val().indexOf(b) !== -1  ) {
    // the code to delete the specific number           
    return false
  }

  if ($("input").val().length > 0) {c = ","}else{ c = ""}

  $('input').val(a + c + b);

});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple replace with a regex should do the trick:

```
$("div").live('click',function() {
  var a = $('input').val();
  var b = $(this).attr('class')
  var c;
  if ( $("input").val().indexOf(b) !== -1  ) {
      $("input").val($("input").val().replace(new RegExp(b+",?|,?"+b, ""),""));
           return false;
  }

  if ($("input").val().length > 0) {c = ","}else{ c = ""}

  $('input').val(a + c + b);

});​
```

Edit: link to JSFiddle Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/g6Hn7/

Comment: can it remove the comma as well IF it exists before the given number? I dont know much about regex thus I cant think of how to fix it

Comment: This: new RegExp(","+b+",?", ""),"") removes the number with the comma if it is not first in the row

Comment: Overlooked that. Changed the regex to incorporate that :-)

Comment: @jQueryBeast: that suggestion is not entirely correct as it also removes the comma between two numbers in some cases (e.g. if you have '1,2,3' and the user clicks on div with class 2 => you get '13', while you want '1,3').

Comment: Yes I've mentioned that, thus I asked you again. Thank you for ur answer

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier if you think of given list as an array as opposed to string. Simply split the string on comma and you can perform standard array operations on it to add/remove elements [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/XCWFr/)

Comment: Okay to be honest, I was going to use this as an array but in a string form so I thought I would place everything in an input an retrieve them when ever I need them; and I could have that input hidden. The problem is that I cannot think of a way to the whole thing without using a string. I am 13 years old so please don't judge me as a bad coder ;p

Comment: You would be very helpful if you could tell me how I can do the same thing but without using the input. Maybe if I can open a new question?

Comment: @jQuerybeast I am not sure what you mean... you need to store the result in a variable?

Comment: Well If I knew how to do it I wouldnt ask so I am not sure if it is a variable but I can imagine it would be a variable. I want your jsfiddle to be stored in the backend so it is not visible (although it gets updated on the clicks etc). Does that make sense?

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you. I just had to figure how to split and join. Swap from an array to string etc but I figured it out